# Custom component (or directive) based on page content in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I want to create component that analize a page content and forms own content depends on it.

For example:

app.component.html

```
...
<body>
    <app-toc-component></app-toc-component>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
```

home.page.html

```
<div>
    ...some content...

    <div id="block1">...</div>
    <div id="block2">...</div>
    <div id="block3">...</div>
    <div id="block4">...</div>
</div>
```

ToC.component.html

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

ToC.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-toc-component',
    templateUrl: './ToC.component.html'
})
export class ToCComponent {
    items: any[];

    // **how and when should I refresh the items array?**
}
```

I need to fill the items array in ToCComponent with elements based on block1-4 and regenerate it on the other page from my application.

Is there a way to achieve it?